Panther overrepresentation test results interpretation
Could you suggest a tutorial or a publication providing example how to interpret, making sense of panther overrepresentation test results?
A little DOI could save my life.
I have a list of regulator genes and I should analyze, if have some connections with a disease.

Ok the Panther Overrepresentation Test (ORT)? What disease and method?

Why not just go straight to source? https://www.pantherdb.org/about.jsp
